creating partion on daily basis on unix time
I'm encountering an error while trying to create partitions for a MySQL table using the following SQL statement:
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ds_shipment_container_new` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `company_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `company_code` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `warehouse_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `warehouse_code` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `shipment_header_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `shipment_number` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `shipment_container_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ship_to_name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ship_to_country` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `carrier` varchar(70) NOT NULL,
  `carrier_service` varchar(70) NOT NULL,
  `carrier_zone_code` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `container_number` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `container_type` varchar(80) DEFAULT NULL,
  `total_quantity` int(11) DEFAULT 0,
  `total_weight` double DEFAULT 0,
  `total_volume` double DEFAULT 0,
  `created_at` int(11) DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
  `updated_at` int(11) DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `updated_at` (`updated_at`) USING BTREE,
  UNIQUE KEY `shipment_container_id` (`shipment_container_id`) USING BTREE
) 
PARTITION BY RANGE (TO_DAYS(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`updated_at`))) (
    PARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DAYS('2023-04-10')),
    PARTITION p2 VALUES LESS THAN (MAXVALUE)
);

The error I'm receiving is:

SQL Error (1486): Constant, random, or timezone-dependent expressions
in (sub)partitioning function are not allowed

I've tried various approaches to resolve this issue, but I'm unable to find a solution. Any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this error would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your assistance.

i also did this
PARTITION BY RANGE (updated_at) (
PARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN (1683244800),  -- Unix timestamp for '2023-04-10 00:00:00'
PARTITION p2 VALUES LESS THAN (MAXVALUE)
);
and getting error that
/* SQL Error (1503): A PRIMARY KEY must include all columns in the table's partitioning function */

I guess created_at int(11) DEFAULT current_timestamp() is a typo and should be created_at timestamp DEFAULT current_timestamp(). See RANGE Partitioning . Even if you fix this with something like demo another error will be thrown. Have a look on Partitioning Keys, Primary Keys, and Unique Keys

@ErgestBasha i have added int(11) because i was using unix time and stores it as int in db but after substituting your solution it still not even if i have made it compound primary key with id it stillsay updated at is not allowed type for partitions

Please edit your question with additional details; unformatted code/data in a comment is not really helpful. It's also important to provide all relevant details (a [mcve]). This includes not only your query, but also sample data, expected vs actual behavior, detailed error output, etc.
